# how to fill between multiple lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this type of graphs:

[image]

code used to generate that graph is

```
    X = np.linspace(0, 3, 5)
    Y1 = X ** 2 + 3
    Y2 = np.exp(X) + 2
    Y3 = np.cos(X)

    plt.plot(Y1, X, lw=4, label='A')
    plt.plot(Y2, X, lw=4, label='B')
    plt.plot(Y3, X, lw=4, label='C')

    plt.legend()
```

I want to fill the graphs between the lines B and C. I tried using `fill_between` and also with `fill` methods available in matplotlib but didn't success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `fill_betweenx(X, Y1, Y2)`

Comment: okay thanks. I didn't know there is method called `fill_betweenx` and that was what I needed :D